# What is "uniform samplerXX iChannel0..3" in this shader?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I happened to see this shader on shader toy.

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ldf3W8

I wanted to know what:

```
uniform samplerXX iChannel0..3;
```

is?

I tried to look at the vertex shader, but I don't find any thing there.

Also how can I convert audio waves to a texture? (which is being done here)

Comment: Warning to anyone who reads this - if you click the link above, it plays music automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wanted to know what uniform samplerXX iChannel0..3; is?

uniforms are externally set variables that have the same value for invocations of the shader during a primitive draw (a vertex shader gets called for each vertex a primitive consists of, fragment shaders for each fragment (which is roughly translates to pixels) drawn to by the primitive).

samplers are OpenGL's way of binding texture units to a shader. In the actual OpenGL program you're loading the texture using `glGenTextures`, `glActiveTexture`, `glBindTexture`, `glTexImage` (and a bunch of other functions, but those are the important ones) and bind the texture unit selected with glActiveTexture to a sampler uniform.

> Also how can I convert audio waves to a texture?

Textures are just interpolated lookup tables. You can place any data you like in a LUT. Most of the time a texture is used for image data, but you can loac PCM samples into it just as well. So you simply fetch PCM data from the audio API and pass it into a texture as data.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.Do you have any references(online/books) as to how the second part(Also how can I convert audio waves to a texture?) can be achieved?

Comment: @user1109536 Any tutorial on *modern* OpenGL will do, since shaders are elementary for its use. I recommend http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut – audio is just a series of scalar values (samples) taken apart by a defines mean timely interval; in the usual case the time intervals are strictly regular and controlled by a precise clock, but the sampling theorem actually allows them to be unevenly spaced if at reconstruction the same timely intervals are used.

Comment: @user1109536 So what you do is reading audio (from a file, the sound card etc.), the way to do this depends on the OS and/or the file format giving you sample data. This sample data is usually organized in so called "frames" or a specific length (usually a few ms of audio samples). The type of each sample usually is either signed or unsigned integer of 8, 16 or 32 bits *or* floating point. Now OpenGL supports the same kind of types for the data type ingested by glTex[Sub]Image1D. So you simply pass your buffer containing a frame of audio to OpenGL as if it were single channel image data.

Comment: Also, there's an example on thadertoy.com which shows [states](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xds3Rr) «The sound is uploaded as a 512x2 texture. First row is the spectrum, second one is the waveform.»